# Will this optical drive work with my MacBook 13in mid 2010

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

Hi I have a 13" MacBook mid 2010 and the optical drive went out so I've been looking for a new one. I found one that I'm interested in but was needing to know if it will work with my MacBook I provided the link to the one I'm looking at.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/2nd-9-5mm-SATA-SSD-Hard-Drive-Caddy-Bay-for-MacBook-CD-DVD-ROM-Optical-Bay-/131975475287?hash=item1eba59f057:g:IdkAAOSwpLNYBwIq

Comment: The linked device in your question will not fit any MacBook or MacBook Pro as they both use a slot-loading SuperDrive on models that support optical media internally.

Comment: I found what I needed down below but thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, this is not actually a replacement Optical Drive. What you're linking to is a caddy that allows you to add a second HDD/SSD to your 13" MacBook by using the space your original Optical Drive was in.

Based on your question, you need something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-Macbook-13-Unibody-A1342-SATA-DVD-RW-Super-Drive-GS23N-with-Cable/331823596487?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D39107%26meid%3D32a6f2dbb3294c608e1f196e62364953%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D162089805188).

Anyone looking to replace one in a MacBook Pro (13" mid-2010) would need something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/UJ8A8-Super-8A8A-SUPERDRIVE-DVD-OPTICAL-DRIVE-Apple-MacBook-Pro-13-A1278-2012-/271824126314?hash=item3f49fb016a:g:kHgAAOSwU-pXp63s).

Comment: I don't believe I have a MacBook Pro all my about mac says is MacBook and I found this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-Macbook-13-Unibody-A1342-SATA-DVD-RW-Super-Drive-GS23N-with-Cable/331823596487?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D39107%26meid%3D32a6f2dbb3294c608e1f196e62364953%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D162089805188

Comment: Okay, that will suit the Model A1342 you have.

Comment: So what I linked should work?

Comment: The Mid-2010 13" MacBook was designated a model number of A1342, and the optical drive [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-Macbook-13-Unibody-A1342-SATA-DVD-RW-Super-Drive-GS23N-with-Cable/331823596487?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D39107%26meid%3D32a6f2dbb3294c608e1f196e62364953%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D162089805188) lists A1342 in the description title, so yes, it should work.